# CSS: background-color only inside the margin

Tags: html, css, margin, background-color

I have searched for an answer but couldn't find it anywhere. My question is reasonably simple: I have a background color of my body, then a large margin, and now I want a different background color **inside** the margin.

How do I do that with CSS?

Comment: you **only** have background _inside the margin_. Box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: if you use a padding instead of a margin, it will then have the background-color you chose for the element

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If your margin is set on the body, then setting the background color of the html tag should color the margin area

```
html { background-color: black; }
body { margin:50px; background-color: white; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3zzb/

Or as dmackerman suggestions, set a margin of 0, but a border of the size you want the margin to be and set the border-color

Comment: or put a `div` #main_container inside the `body` to do the same thing

Comment: If your background color on the html tag is any color than white, when the page first loads, the color takes up the whole page for a second, before the color of the body kicks in, so it looks kind of weird.

Comment: @AlexF - outlook emails are not standard html, you are extremely limited in what you can do.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of using a margin, could you use a border? You should do this with `<div>`, anyway.

Something like this?[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/GBTHv/

Comment: Hi, I've done something similar, but the background color inside the border only extends to the bottom of the text inside the margin. I need it to be inside the whole margin area.. if that makes sense.

Comment: @user1318194 - I think you're confused by what margin means.  Margin is the area around the element, so a border like above is exactly what margin is.

Comment: Yeah, but with margins you can set it by percentage - borders you can't. So you if want a margin of 1% on the left and right, you won't be able to do that with borders.

Comment: if the color is transparent, then the border color will blend with the background color.

Answer (score 8):

I needed something similar, and came up with using the :before (or :after) pseudoclasses:

```
#mydiv {
   background-color: #fbb;
   margin-top: 100px;
   position: relative;
}
#mydiv:before {
   content: "";
   background-color: #bfb;
   top: -100px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9kv02gu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible du to the Box Model.
However you could use a workaround with css3's border-image, or border-color in general css.

However im unsure whether you may have a problem with resetting.
Some browsers do set a margin to html as well. See Eric Meyers Reset CSS for more!

```
html{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Comment: if the color is transparent, then the border color will blend with the background color.

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly looking to change the margin color outside the border?  Maybe [outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) outline will help? Particularly

```
outline-color: green;
```

Comment: Or `box-shadow` https://stackoverflow.com/a/18841365/4854931