# css outline left and right

Tags: css

Anyway to set css `outline` only show left and right ? Because I can't use border, I tried but it will make more bad outlook .

```css
.test{
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  outline:10px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Can't be done with the outline property. Per the spec: The outline is the same on all sides. In contrast to borders, there is no 'outline-top' or 'outline-left' property

Comment: possible duplicate of [outline on only one border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671898/outline-on-only-one-border)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could possibly achieve this using two box shadows:

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 0px 0px black, 5px 0px 0px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm!

Comment: @Andrew Not quite sure what you mean? The [Box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property allows you to apply multiple values in a single declaration.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said, which is true.

Comment: Is there a performance hit compared to just an outline?

Comment: @Andrew - I'm confused by your comments; nobody claimed there was a `box-shadow-right`. There's also no property called `box-shadow-lollipop`...  [`outline` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/outline) And, as j08691 pointed out, there is no `outline-left` or 'outline-right`, and so jbutler483 offered a (rather creative) alternative method of achieving the same result using `box-shadow` to draw a [solid] "shadow" on any of the top, bottom, left, or right, as desired.