# How to prevent background color of a body tag from spilling onto it's margin

Tags: css, margin, background-color

I'm writing a very simple css code which is listed below:

```
body {
background-color:#616161;
margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Even though I've specified a 20% margin on the left side, the background color affects the margin area of the body tag as well. How do I ensure that the background color remains within the border?

Comment: use a DIV to enclose the area you want to have background color, and add background-color CSS in DIV instead of body

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048800/css-background-color-only-inside-the-margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a div to put the background color in

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="background">
<p>This is some text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then use this CSS to assign the color and the margin, you have to tweak the code to get the width and height where you want it

```
html{
height:100%;
}
body{
height:100%;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left: 20%;
}
.background{
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
background-color:#616161;
width:100%;
}
```

Or as miro pointed out:

```
html { background-color:#fff; }
body {
background-color:#616161;
margin:0% 0% 0% 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found nice description for this browser behaviour: *"Background properties on the body element will propagate to the html element (the viewport), but only if the latter’s computed value for the background property is transparent."* ([link](http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/#comment-877063)) + ([testing fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gnu4t/1/)).

The best solution here is to use the additional `div` just like `user2067005` has suggested above.
W3C recommends:

> > **For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.** For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for 'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must instead use the computed value of the background properties from that element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root element. ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background))