# How to visually show padding and margin in visual editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a tool in which when you hover over an element, it gets highlighted (I do it by applying box-shadow with large radius so that it tints the element). I would now like to also visually show the padding and margin, but I don't know how to accomplish this and show it like in the inspector. Does anyone have any experience with this?

My tool description: I'm building a tool similar to WebFlow that allows to open up a page, perform modifications (change text, some CSS rules etc) there and share the updated page among colleagues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping the div inside another for coloured margins.

Refering the link [coloured padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048800/css-background-color-only-inside-the-margin) for adding coloured padding.

**Note:** *for margins I have used the property "display:flow-root", I am not sure if this is the best property, it may have cross browser issues.*

this is with HTML and CSS alone, if you use javascript you can just get the properties of the element and add styling automatically.

```css
.tester{
  padding:15px;
  margin:15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 0%, rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 0%, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 100%);
    background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color:gray;
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tester">
  gray is for margin and red is for padding
  </div>
</div>
```